# Regex to match illegal characters in a chatroom string

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, chat

I am developing a network of chatrooms such as one that may be found on IRC.

To join a chatroom, users can use the /join room command.

**For example:**
`/join #main` to go to the main chatroom

However, if variable room contains an illegal character, for example: `/join #&*YHj`, the system breaks.

How can I match the illegal characters with regex in the variable room to prevent users from accessing these rooms?

Note: The prefix hash will not be matched by this regex

Comment: Do you have any code at all for this? What qualifies as an illegal character?

Comment: do you mean `string.match(/[\#\$\%\?\&\!\@]/).length != 0` ?

Comment: @lincolnk anything that is not a letter number or underscore

Comment: `if (/\W/.test(room)) alert('Yuk...');`

Comment: `\W` would do it. (matches anything other than a letter, number or underscore).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
if (/\W/.test(room)) alert('yuk...');
```

If so, try this :

```
if (!/^#\w+$/.test(room)) alert('boom!');
```

Comment: # is not matched, it is part of the roomname

Comment: @BenJohnsonmk2 So, do you want to check if the first char is a `#`?

Comment: @BenJohnsonmk2 Scroll to bottom : http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/redev2.shtml.